# regex in bash expression

Tags: regex, bash, expression

I have 2 questions about regex in bash expression.

1.non-greedy mode

```
local temp_input='"a1b", "d" , "45"'
if [[ $temp_input =~ \".*?\" ]]
then
    echo ${BASH_REMATCH[0]}
fi
```

The result is

```
"a1b", "d" , "45"
```

In java

```
String str = "\"a1b\", \"d\" , \"45\"";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\".*?\"").matcher(str);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

I can get the result below.

```
"a1b"
"d"
"45"
```

But how can I use non-greedy mode in bash?
I can understand why the \"[^\"]*\" works.

But I don't understand why does the \".*?\" do not work.

2.global matches

```
local temp_input='abcba'
if [[ $temp_input =~ b ]]
then
    #I wanna echo 2 b here. 
    #How can I set the global flag?
fi
```

How can I get all the matches?
ps:I only wanna use regex.

For the second question, sorry for the confusing.
I want to echo "b" and "b", not count "b".

Help!

Comment: `bash` regular expressions do not have a non-greedy mode. See `man 7 regex` for what is supported.

Comment: @chepner Thanks for your help. I also find nothing about non-greedy mode in the specific. I think you're right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your first question, an alternative is this:

```
[[ $temp_input =~ \"[^\"]*\" ]]
```

For your second question, you can do this:

```
temp_input=abcba
t=${temp_input//b}
echo "$(( (${#temp_input} - ${#t}) / 1 )) b"
```

Or for convenience place it on a function:

```
function count_matches {
    local -i c1=${#1} c2=${#2}
    if [[ c2 -gt 0 && c1 -ge c2 ]]; then
        local t=${1//"$2"}
        echo "$(( (c1 - ${#t}) / c2 )) $2"
    else
        echo "0 $2"
    fi
}

count_matches abcba b
```

Both produces output:

```
2 b
```

Update:

If you want to see the matches you can use a function like this. You can also try other regular expressions not just literals.

```
function find_matches {
    MATCHES=() 
    local STR=$1 RE="($2)(.*)"
    while [[ -n $STR && $STR =~ $RE ]]; do
        MATCHES+=("${BASH_REMATCH[1]}")
        STR=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
    done
}
```

Example:

```
> find_matches abcba b
> echo "${MATCHES[@]}"
b b

> find_matches abcbaaccbad 'a.'
> echo "${MATCHES[@]}"
ab aa ad
```

Comment: Thanks for you help. Sorry for confusing you. For the second question, I want b and b, not count "b".

Comment: I can understand why the \"[^\"]*\" works. But I don't understand why does the \".*?\" do not work.

Comment: @android_su Probably because bash does not implement it, or interprets it a different way. In a strict sense of interpreting `\".*?\"` I believe bash is not wrong anyway. The feature is just available in other programs. I made an update by the way.

Comment: Thanks for your great help! But I still want to know how to use non-greedy mode in bash expression.

Answer (score 2):

1. Your regular expression matches the string starting with the first quotation mark (before `ab`) and ending with the last quotation mark (after `ef`).  This is greedy, even though your intention was to use a non-greedy match (`*?`).  It seems that bash uses POSIX.2 regular expression (check your `man 7 regex`), which does not support a non-greedy Kleene star.

   If you want just `"ab"`, I'd suggest a different regular expression:

   ```
   if [[ $temp_input =~ \"[^\"]*\" ]]
   ```

   which explicitly says that you don't want quotation marks inside your strings.
2. I don't understand what you mean.  If you want to find all matches (and there are two occurrences of `b` here), I think you cannot do it with a single `~=` match.

Comment: Thanks for your help. For the first question, I can understand your regex string, but I wanna know why does mine do not work. For the second question, could you give me a good way to get the two "b"s please? I am a beginner for the bash.

Answer (score 1):

This is my first post, and I am very amateur at bash, so apologies if I haven't understood the question, but I wrote a function for non-greedy regex using entirely bash:

```
regex_non_greedy () {
    local string="$1"
    local regex="$2"
    local replace="$3"

    while [[ $string =~ $regex ]]; do
        local search=${BASH_REMATCH}
        string=${string/$search/$replace}
    done

    printf "%s" "$string"
}
```

Example invocation:

```
regex_non_greedy "all cats are grey and green" "gre+." "white"
```

Which returns:

```
all cats are white and white
```