# bash regex to parse text of the form +incdir+<dir1>+<dir2>

Tags: regex, bash

I have an input string of the form `+incdir+<dir1>+<dir2>`, where `<dir1>` and `<dir2>` are directory names. I want to parse this using a bash regex and have the values of the directories inside BASH_REMATCH[1], [2], ...

Here is what I tried:

```
function match {
  if [[ "$1" =~ \+incdir(\+.*)+ ]]; then
    for i in $(seq $(expr ${#BASH_REMATCH[@]} - 1)); do
      echo $i ":" ${BASH_REMATCH[$i]}
    done
  else
    echo "no match"
  fi
}
```

This works for `match +incdir+foo`, but doesn't for `match +incdir+foo+bar`, because it does greedy matching and it outputs `+foo+bar`. There isn't any non-greedy matching in bash as [regex in bash expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18738576/regex-in-bash-expression) mentions so I tried the following for the pattern: `\+incdir(\+[^+]*)+` but this just gives me `+bar`.

The way I would interpret the regex is the following: find the beginning `+incdir`, then match me at least one group starting with a `+` followed by as many characters as you can find that are not `+`. When you hit a `+` this is the start of the next group. I guess my reasoning is incorrect.

Does anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Why insist on using BASH_REMATCH rather than parameter expansion? Choosing the right tool for a job is half the battle.

Comment: As an aside, the `function` keyword is needlessly incompatible with POSIX sh. Better to be in the habit of using `match() { ... }`, with no `function` keyword preceding.

Comment: Also, `seq` is a nonstandard tool -- it's not part of bash, it's not part of POSIX. Better to use a `for ((i=0; i<whatever; i++))` type loop.

Comment: Anyhow -- one `(...)` in your text translates into exactly one `BASH_REMATCH` array entry. You absolutely can't (as of bash 4.3) have a single pair of parens translate into multiple groups in the output, even if that group can appear more than once; the array entry gets the content from one, and only one, match in that case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using only bash builtins (but NOT regular expressions, which are the wrong tool for this job):

```
match() {
    [[ $1 = *+incdir+* ]] || return              # noop if no +incdir present
    IFS=+ read -r -a pieces <<<"${1#*+incdir+}"  # read everything after +incdir+
                                                 # into +-separated array
    for idx in "${!pieces[@]}"; do               # iterate over keys in array
      echo "$idx: ${pieces[$idx]}"               # ...and emit key/value pairs
    done
}

$ match "yadda yadda +incdir+foo+bar+baz"
0: foo
1: bar
2: baz
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @CharlesDuffy! A quick follow up question if I may. I had no idea that parameter expansion exists (bash newbie), but if this isn't what regular expressions are suited for, then can you give me an example of where they should be used?

Comment: As for parameter expansion -- I strongly suggest http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/073 (and docs linked from same) as a reference. In terms of what regexes are good for... well, they're good for patterns that can't be described without them, circular though this description is.